# Java. Read a base class of object sent by ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, server, client

I have 3 modules:

- server
- client
- serverAPI (available in both modules as .jar file)

I have also a Frame class (in serverAPI module):

```
public class Frame implements Serializable {
    private final FrameTypesInterface type;
    private final Object[] objects;
    ...
}
```

- serverAPI module have UserAPI class.
- server module have User class extending UserAPI.

When client connects and tries to login an request is sent to server. Then server creates User and put it into frame and sends it back.

```
server.User user = new server.User(); // User extends serverAPI.UserAPI
Frame frame = new Frame(LOGIN, new Object[] { user });
objectOutputStream.writeObject(frame)
```

And now, on a Client module side, I'm trying to receive the frame:

```
frame = (Frame)objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Frame is received but exception is also thrown:

`(ClassNotFoundException) Class not found: server.User`

In fact on client side server.User is not available, but instead of it (a base class) serverAPI.UserAPI is available.

I would like to keep current concept (create User extending UserAPI on server side and receive UserAPI on client side). How can I do that?

Comment: I think this should not be possible. You need the class definition of `server.User` on the client side as well. How shall the JVM execute code of your `server.User` class if it does not know the method definitions?

Comment: On a client side I need only base class (UserAPI). I hope it would be possible to cast somehow User to UserAPI during transmission

Comment: Use Externizable and customize your serialization

Comment: thanks, for now I decided to use Client in API module like Till Rohrmann said.